# Порядок генитивной конструкции в предложении «Экспресс-поезд до станции NN отправится от пятой платформы пятого пути.»

Tags: синтаксис, семантика

Услышал на станции пригородных электричек такое сообщение:

> Экспресс-поезд до станции NN отправится от пятой платформы пятого пути.

*Вопрос.* Почему генитивная конструкция здесь использована именно в таком порядке, а не наоборот: «от пятого пути пятой платформы»?

П.С. Пространственная структура станции пригородных электричек выглядит так: пассажир идёт на одну из платформ, с одной или с двух сторон от которых располагаются железнодорожные пути. Бывают ситуации, когда один путь одновременно принадлежит двум платформам.

Comment: Плюсик - за наблюдательность, а не за логику.

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно. Поезд **отправляется от платформы**, а по пути он движется (поезд "**от пути**" *не отправляется*). Та платформа, от которой он отправляется, принадлежит пятому пути и пронумерована как пятая в числе приписанных этому пути платформ. Иная последовательность была бы при формальном указании **места отправления**, аналогично российскому почтовому *адресу*:

> Место отправления поезда: *пятый путь, пятая платформа.*

То обстоятельство, что при составлении формального *адреса* последовательность *инвертируется* в направлении "от общего к частному" - чисто русскоязычная традиция. Такого нет, например, в английском указании адреса: мало того, что Холмс "жил в доме 221Б по Бекер-стрит" (последовательность та же, что и в русском случае с платформой или любым адресом), ещё и адрес этот в английском варианте записывается в той же последовательности (221B, Baker Street).

Comment: *Та платформа, от которой он отправляется, принадлежит пятому пути и пронумерована как пятая в числе приписанных этому пути платформ.* - это не так. У платформ сквозная нумерация. То есть платформа-то пути в какои-то смысле принадлежит (я в своем ответе об этом пишу), но номер её никак не сообразуется с конкретным "путем".

Comment: И еще. Как бы вы в соответствии с вашими тезисами сформулировали ситуацию, когда поезд проходит без остановки *по шестому мимо пятой платформы*? Такое изредка встречается, объявление дается чтобы предупредить одичавшую публику на этой самой пятой платформе, чтоб не паниковали, не толкались и не бросались с перрона. Я знаю, но не скажу - это перебор будет.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что любой вопрос, начинающийся с "почему" обычно не имеет ответа, *потому что гладиолус*. Так уж принято на железной дороге начинать с более важного.

Хотя тут вопрос ещё и фактической неточностью страдает.
Во-первых, на железной дороге вопреки вашему представлению, платформа принадлежит пути, а не наоборот. Дело в том, что понятие "путь" там несколько специфично, если упрощенно, это кусок полотна от стрелки до стрелки, а все, что там еще понастроено, этому "пути" принадлежит. Казалось бы все объясняет, но не тут-то было.

Ибо есть еще "во-вторых", вы, судя по всему, назвали "генетивной конструкцией" притяжательную функцию родительного падежа, что не совсем верно.
Вообще в русском языке выделяют (при классическом счете падежей) как минимум три функции родительного: притяжательную (ножка стола), аблативную (она же "исходная" - выйти из дома, отошел от остановки) и разделительную (один из нас).
Так вот, в подслушанном вами тексте нет притяжатености, хотя "генетивная конструкция" присутствует за счет аблатива: **"Поезд отправляется от (....) пятого пути"**.
В данной грамматической форме путь платформе не принадлежит. Равно как и наоборот.
Наверное, правильно было бы написать через запятую: "отправится от шестой платформы, пятого пути", но так почему-то не принято. Можно спорить, насколько все это грамотно, но смысл в подобных сообщениях вокзального диктора именно такой.

Чтобы в этом убедиться достаточно чуть подольше постоять на какой-нибудь небольшой  станции, и вы, ручаюсь, услышите нечто наподобие ***"Ко второй платформе пятому пути прибывает..."*** или еще интереснее ***"На вторую платформу пятый путь прибывает..."*** Генетивной конструкции тут нет и в помине.
Вот такой у них язык, железнодорожный.

Answer (score 1):

Р.п. использован верно, если **считать**, что один (пятый) путь выходит на две платформы (пятую и шестую).  Тогда  выражение **пятая платформа пятого пути** **УСЛОВНО** означает принадлежность пятой платформы пятому пути (путь как бы имеет две платформы). Если считать наоборот, то есть платформа имеет два пути, то выражение становится некорректным.

Но так как всё это **условности**, то  лучше использовать сочетание **пятая платформа пятого пути**, где на первом месте стоит нужная по порядку **координата** (сначала идем на платформу, а потом выбираем путь).Фактически это **устойчивое обозначение координат**, принятое на практике, но при желании можно объяснить его грамматику.

Правильный вариант: **поезд отправляется  ОТ пятой платформы  пятого пути** или **прибывает на пятую платформу пятого пути**. (Имеется в виду **удаление** ОТ всего вокзального комплекса, состоящего из платформ и путей.)

Предлог С может иметь обобщенное пространственное значение С; 1. кого-чего. Указывает на место, предмет, лицо, явление и т.п., ОТКУДА направлено движение или действие. Примеры: Вовкина мать дала адрес, рассказала, как и **с какого вокзала** ехать на электричке [Алексей Моторов. (2013)] **С какого пути** пойдет? ― спросил Баклаков. [Олег Куваев. (1970-1975)] –

Comment: "C пути" обычно сходят, сбиваются или сворачивают - такова стандартная сочетаемость, поэтому таким объявлением можно смутить суеверную часть пассажиров. Путь даже в условном смысле не может "принадлежать" платформе, которая технически вторична (поезд и без неё поедет, если есть путь) и для этого к нему примыкает, тем самым физически принадлежа. На одном московском вокзале (видимо, по этой причине) даже планируют покончить с нумерацией платформ, развесив над платформами соотв. путей только номера путей.

Comment: А вы как спросите: "От какого пути отправляется поезд?" Или как вы объявите: "Поезд отправляется от пятого пути"?  Как-то не очень корректно звучит. А когда вы ищете свой поезд, то вам нужен только номер пути.  Вы к нему или сразу идете по указателю, или сначала ищете платформу, а потом путь.Всё же очень просто, и никаких суеверий.

Comment: *Правильный вариант:  поезд отправляется с пятой платформы пятого пути* - ???

Comment: Поезд отправляется в лучшем случае **от платформы**. А "с платформы" можно разве что бросится - с целью суицида, например.

Comment: Спасибо,смешно. Пространственная интерпретация предлога С выглядит именно так, но и у предлога ОТ она тоже небезупречна. Строго говоря, удаляющийся поезд не отъезжает от платформы, он едет вдоль платформы, а удаляется он всего вокзального комплекса. От пятого пути он тоже не может отправиться, так как раз и передвигается по этому пути. Поэтому значения у предлогов должны быть обобщенные, а не чисто пространственные. Вот если соединить платформу с путями или путь с платформами, то, пожалуй, предлог ОТ лучше подойдет., я его, пожалуй, исправлю.

Comment: А как вы скажете: От/с какого пути отправляется поезд? Или объявите: Поезд отправляется от/с пятой платформы? И еще интересно, эта профессиональная речь где-нибудь нормируется?  Кстати, для суицида современная платформа может и не подойти. Говорят, что это теперь кусок "асфальта" между путями.